# Powershell Control Windows Search through command line

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to write a powershell script that will disable indexing on some drives but keep it activated on some others (ex: C:).

Has anyone done it before ?

Thanks

Comment: on what operative system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, (not tested):

```
function Disable-Indexing{
    Param($Drive)
    $obj = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Volume -Filter "DriveLetter='$Drive'"
    $indexing = $obj.IndexingEnabled
    if("$indexing" -eq $True){
        write-host "Disabling indexing of drive $Drive"
        $obj | Set-WmiInstance -Arguments @{IndexingEnabled=$False} | Out-Null
    }
}

use:

disable-indexing "c:"
```

Comment: Thanks. I have found the same on this forum [link](http://powershellcommunity.org/Forums/tabid/54/aft/7644/Default.aspx)

Comment: I'm a bit disappointed that this isn't part of a [built-in storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/?view=windowsserver2019-ps) cmdlet.